# Using CSS with mail() function in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, email

I'm having a problem with css and php mail function, and I can't figure out why parts of the styling sheet is not working.

This is my php function which sends the email to the user:

```
    <?php
require 'dbconnection.php';

//Testing variables
$name = "laerte";
$email = "someemail@gmail.com";
$title = "Some Project";
$desc = " Some description";

//adds project to MYSQL database
//The function returns uniqid generated
$id = addProject($title,$desc,$name);

$subject = "Project: ".$title;
$header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$header .= "From: pixelgraphy.net";
$message = "<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        body
        {
            width: 700px;
            height: auto;
        }
        h1
        {
            background-color: blue;
            color:white;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            text-align:center;
        }
        #message
        {
            width: 500px;
            height: auto;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        #sign
        {
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Request For Feedback</h1>
        <div id = 'message'>

            <p>".$name."  , thank you for submting your idea  The project <b> ".  
            $title." </b> has been added to RFF's view list </p>  
            <a href ='www.pixelgraphy.net/assignment8/getcomments.php?id=".$id."   
            '>Click here</a> to view RFF's list of projects 
        </div>
        <div id = 'sign'> Sinceraly, Anthony Paveglio & Laerte Sousa </div> 
    </body>
                </html>";

    //sends the email           
    mail($email,$subject,$message,$header);

    ?>
```

if i echo $message to the page, everything is fine:

no longer available.

but the message sent to my email comes like this:

no longer available.

For some reason all the styling after the title does not work, and i can't figure out why. any help or tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `inline` CSS. Most Email services will tear your stylesheet apart, *literally*.

Comment: Inline everything. There are some tools to do this for your HTML template automatically. http://premailer.dialect.ca/ and http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/ are some examples.

Comment: Use regular `CSS` to build it (as it's easier), then when you're happy with the output use a tool to convert the `CSS` into inline styles as mentioned above. Almost no extra overhead dev time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more better and useful way:

```
<div id="message" style="background-color: blue !important;color: white !important;">
```

As you know, `!important` ignore the another style rules.

Answer (score 5):

You need to forget everything you know about regular web design if you want to create HTML mails. Most webmail services, including Gmail (which you seem to be using) applies rigorous filtering on all HTML and will blatantly strip away everything if you do anything they might not approve of.

First of all, last time I checked, Gmail doesn't support style-tags at all, in fact, merely including a head or body tag may break everything. The best approach is to not use any CSS at all and rely on the good old table layouts of the nineties. If you really have to use CSS, you will need to inline it.

Additionally, you should create some outlook.com, yahoo.com and icloud.com accounts to make sure that you at least cover the most common webmail services. In my experience, iCloud is the easiest of them to code for since it merely displays the mail inside an iframe with very little, if any, formatting at all.

Lastly, while it's impossible to be sure without actually testing it, I've noticed that Gmail sometime dislike text with color:white as well as a-tags with color:black. Setting the colour to something like #EFEFEF or #010101, respectively, may solve that though.

Comment: this is right, and Gmail itself has some more unintuitive limitations: ignoring CSS properties like "display" or "box-shadow", not allowing web fonts etc. See https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-gmail-and-css-part-1 for a good start, I managed to display my template the way I wanted using this knowledge + some email inliner tool

Answer (score 2):

Change your styling from **ID** to **CLASS**.  The IDs are sometimes changed.

For example:

```css
    .message
    {
        width: 500px;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .sign
    {
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

And then you obviously change

```html
<div id="message">
```

to

```html
<div class="message">
```

Comment: I think the inline styling is more better in sending emails, also better than `ID` and `Class`. because some of the mail servers, change the value of element attribiutes.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the problem still persisted.

Comment: *"but the problem still persisted."* - [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664282/using-css-with-mail-function-in-php#comment29201838_19664282)

Comment: I'm going to try doing it inline.

Comment: @LaerteSousaNeto You will have better results doing it that way, even though it's more work, it's well worth the effort. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, it works as long as i do it inline, it is a little bit messy, but I'll figure out a way to make it more organized, perhaps using string variables.